# How to make center alignment for a wxScrolledWindow?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

There is a wxScrolledWindow with logical coordinates (1000, 12040). When the window is resized, i.e. maximized, I want to keep it center alignment in the client view.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to catch wxEVT_SIZE, and manually adjust the scroll position based on the old vs new size.

Comment: At initializing, the scroll window logical width is smaller than the client rectangle width. In other words, the horizontal scroll bar is not visible. How to make the drawing aligned at horizontal center?

Comment: In that case, then you would just be forced to increase the client size of the scrolled window.